# HP Pavilion dv6000 Laptop: No sound coming from speakers

Tags: windows-7, laptop, speakers

I have face problem with my laptop (HP dv6000), ?
i am wonder with this problem, because the system working fine with Headphones but no sound it all with speaker, even the system volume bar is also working and show the lower and high sound for speaker,,, but no sound.....

Is there any solution ? ... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your speakers are either broken or disconnected.  The fact that headphones work shows that the soundcard and drivers are working.

If your speakers are broken, you'll need to replace them.  There is a chance that the wire connecting the speakers to the soundcard got disconnected somehow.  In either case, opening a laptop is very tricky.  There are often many little plastic hooks that you can easily break.

Comment: For broken [built-in] speakers, if the laptop is covered under warranty, don't open it (this could void the warranty)!  Instead, send it to the vendor's RMA department for the free repair service that the warranty entitles you to.

Comment: @Chris Ting, yes you are right my laptop soundcard and drivers are working... and sometime loud sound also produce sound on speakers but not clear... and i think this happened by headphones entering... but now i am stuck how to repair it or connect the wires.... any idea sir.

Comment: @Randolf Richardson, NO, my laptop is not in warranty yet... wanna do something to repair it...

Comment: @ime:  Aw shucks!  It never hurts to check though.  =)

Comment: @Randolf Richardson, i did't understand, would you like to explain..

Comment: This is probably a mechanical/electrical failure of the headphone jack. Most jacks these days disconnect the internal speakers when headphones are inserted. When this mechanism fails, the speakers stay in disconnected mode even without headphones plugged in. Sometimes you can kick it back to life inserting/removing the headphones a few times, and giving the jack a bit of a wiggle when connected.

Comment: @SPectre, thanks for trick, but this method i already apply but no success, i am stuck now what to do... Can i open the laptop and can i fix by it self by checking the jack...?